# Bootstrap Carousel cut image in half while loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Using the bootstrap carousel, and while each image is loading, the images are cut vertically in half, only become ok when fully loaded.

The code i am using came from Boostrap website.

What am i missing?

```
<div class="container">
<div id="largoheady">


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/heady.jpg" title="something " alt="something" > 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/heady.jpg" title="something " alt="something" > 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/heady.jpg" title="something " alt="something" border="0" class="img-responsive"> 
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/heady.jpg" title="something " alt="something" border="0" class="img-responsive"> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Edited to add 2 images. First one shows what happens while image loading. Second image shows full slider.

[image: Bootstrap Carousel cut image in half while loading]

[image: Bootstrap Carousel]

Comment: kindly attache a screenshot if posible

Comment: Kindly share a working demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS:

```
.carousel-inner > .item img{
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working - It was an error in my custom CSS file.

As soon as I got rid of it, the bootstrap carousel worked as it should.

I had an old piece of code from a "responsive-container", and that piece of css was messing with the output of the carousel.

Bad code out > carousel working perfectly!

Thanks! Hope anyone else with same issues can solve them too.